# Automatically fill out a form one another domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, web-scraping

I have a webpage that I have a search field.

**The question:**

What I want to do is take this search fields data and use this to fill out a field on another website and click on submit on that page. The problem is that the other webpage is on another domain (and I do not have access to this website). Is there a way to do this? Web scraping? I would prefer to use `c# / ASP.Net`

Comment: Wouldn't that be cross-site scripting? If so, it is something that the website you are trying to hit is likely doing everything in their power to prevent.

Comment: I didn't think it was XSS, so pre-filling a search box with what you have on your webpage is XSS? Is that any different from having an autofill application in your browser? EDIT: YES right from the definition: A cross-site scripting vulnerability may be used by attackers to bypass access controls such as the same-origin policy.

Comment: The difference with the auto complete in the browser is that it is not originating from another website.